# Shopware 6.5 Twig Exceptions: Blank Page instead of Symfony Error Page

Tags: symfony, shopware6, ddev

## Twig Exceptions not displaying as Error Page in Shopware 6.5 using DDEV

I initialized a new Shopware 6.5 Project with ddev using the symfony flex template.

Normally, any exception in the symfony-context should be rendered as error page. This works fine for normal PHP-Exceptions. However, any Exception produced by a Twig-Template (eg. `if`-statement spelled as `iff`) shows a blank page instead of an error page. The correct error does get logged in the server log, still.

For better reproducibility, here is the `config.yaml` I used:

```yaml
name: shopware-project
type: shopware6
docroot: public
php_version: "8.1"
developer_mode: true
webserver_type: apache-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: true
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
database:
    type: mariadb
    version: "10.4"
nfs_mount_enabled: false
mutagen_enabled: false
use_dns_when_possible: false
composer_version: "2"
web_environment: []
nodejs_version: "16"
disable_settings_management: true
```

I allready tracked this down to the `Response`-Class under `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php` using X-Debug. If I uncomment line 422 (`$this->sendHeaders();`) everything works fine and I can see the correct error page. So I thought it should have somethind to do with the ddev-server config.

In addition to that: If I run the same project-folder using MAMP with identical database, it just works fine and I have no problem seeing error pages. The header information of the ddev container and the MAMP-Server do not differ.

Comment: It looks like you've done some excellent debugging. I guess you're seeing the error in `ddev logs` if I understand right? Have you tried using the `nginx-fpm` webserver type to see if that has any different results?

Comment: Thank you! That's correct, I see the the error in the ddev logs or, if I specify a log file through a custom php.ini, it's also listed there.

I indeed tried using `nginx-fpm`, but with no luck!
The feason I switched to `apache-fpm` in the first place was, because the  `shopware-installer.phar.php` did not load the included assets correctly  - but that's a different problem!

Comment: Sorry for the misleading information in my last comment:
I see the error in the Shopware Logfile (`./var/log/dev.log`) or a logfile specified through a custom php.ini.

I tried `ddev logs`now and got the following output (maybe that helps):

Comment: [Tue Jul 18 14:16:12.629967 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2123] [client 172.28.0.6:59724] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Tue Jul 18 14:16:12.629988 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2123] [client 172.28.0.6:59724] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Tue Jul 18 14:16:12.629990 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2123] (22)Invalid argument: [client 172.28.0.6:59724] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :

Comment: That error looks like it's probably normal for the situation I would imagine. to pursue this you'll have to figure out if the problem is happening at the php-fpm level or apache/nginx. I think your excellent debugging skills will get you to the answer.

Comment: I tried adjusting `php.ini`- and Apache-Settings (through Dockerfile), but with no luck.

Comment: Unless you say what settings you tried to adjust and where we can't get much farther. This may be a better discussion for the DDEV discord (https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k) or the issue queue, https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues, but I suspect it's really not about DDEV at all. If you file an issue, please give the details, like where you made changes and what changes you made and why.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send the errors with the standard DDEV configuration, the php.ini must be adjusted.

Due to the length of the error message, which is processed with preg_replace_callback in `vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorRenderer/HtmlErrorRenderer.php:307`, a PHP error occurs, because preg_ does not work with the opposite string length.

If you set `pcre.backtrack_limit=5000000` in php.ini, the error is replaced correctly.

However, this causes a new error to occur in nginx/apache:

```
[error] 1931#1931: *3 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.29.0.5, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.ddev.site`
```

Am currently still looking for a solution to the nginx problem.